# VueJS library components have no autocomplete in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, nuxt.js

I've created a Vue.JS components library with ui components like Modal and Tab. It's configured to build to a dist/ dir and is hosted on a private git repository. When importing components in my Nuxt.js application I never get the Intellij autocomplete for the properties.

For import I use named imports and can also see the ReadMe content when hovering over the library but can never see any information regarding the components.

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.2 with Emmett and Vue.JS plugins

Is it possible that the build removes too much information for IntelliJ or do I have to provide IntelliJ with some sort of file or scheme to get autocomplete working?

Comment: In most cases the IDE can't get much information from minified files. You might consider adding .d.ts files.

Comment: Thank you, .d.ts would be great except we don't use typescript (yet) in our .vue files. I have read that .d.ts is not possible for javascript based .vue components.